# How to make a transition from image view to color?

Tags: swift3, imageview, uicolor, transition

I was wondering how to make a transition from an image view to another color so that it appears like the image view "flows" into the background color in Swift 3. I tried it with gradient views but it didn't look nearly as good like in the following picture:

[image: Picture with image view and background color]

Comment: Are you saying that you want an image view to animate and change the colorful image into black and white? I'm confused when you say *transition from an image view to another color*

Comment: No, I'm sorry, it's hard to explain in another language. You see, in the picture is at the bottom the background color white and in the top there is an image view. And what I want is that fading from the image to the color, just like a gradient view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a gradient layer on top of your image view. The gradient is transferring from transparent to white so you have the blue effect on the bottom of your image view. Here I have an image view with red color

[image]

The code is like this. This code is creating a layer that covers the entire image view, and do the gradient from top to bottom. If you want it to start from the half of the screen, see the line with comment that set the frame for the layer. You just need to do something like `frame.y = y + height / 2`

```
let layer = CAGradientLayer()
layer.frame = self.imageView.bounds// Change this line.
layer.colors = [
    UIColor.white.cgColor,
    UIColor.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor
]
self.imageView.layer.mask = layer
```

The output looks like this

[image]